# running celery with specific linux user

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am using celery with Django app. I am using specific user to run the app. I can run django server with specific user - deployer but cant run the celery process with that user. Its starting the celery with root user. So, I cant use environment variable from that user profile (~/.bashrc).

Configuration of celery:

```
[program:celery_supervisor]
environment=PYTHONPATH=PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/koob/fireball/
direcotry=/usr/local/koob/fireball/
command=/usr/local/koob/fireball/env/bin/python /usr/local/koob/fireball/env/bin/celery -A fireball worker -l info
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=deployer
stderr_logfile=/usr/local/koob/fireball/celery.err.log
stdout_logfile=/usr/local/koob/fireball/celery.out.log
```

Configuration of django:

```
[program:fireball_supervisor]
directory=/usr/local/koob/fireball/
environment=PLAY_ENV=production
command=uwsgi --ini fireball.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/usr/local/koob/fireball/fireball.err.log
stdout_logfile=/usr/local/koob/fireball/fireball.out.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that user doesn't exist? Anyway, that's a bug:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4201

You should be able to use --uid:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.celery.html#cmdoption-celery-uid

To know "deployer" uid:

```
id -u deployer
```